# Issue with pd.read_sql and MSSQL using OFFSET Fetch

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

SQl Server 2022 Python 3.11 and Pandas 2.02 and SqlAlchemy 1.4.41 on Windows

```
query = f"select * from A01ASSMF as MF LEFT OUTER JOIN A01AEXT as A01A ON MF.A01_ASSETID = A01A.A01A_ASSETID LEFT OUTER JOIN A04INVIT as A04 ON MF.A01_ASSETID = A04.A04_ASSETID ORDER BY MF.A01_ASSETID OFFSET {row_from} ROWS FETCH NEXT {row_count} ROWS ONLY"
```

When I use a01_df = pd.read_sql(query, conn) I get 5000 rows as expected but all the data in the dataframe is Nan

When I do this it works fine - reading the sql data via sqlalchemy fetch and construction a df from it.

```
with dbconnection.connect() as conn:
       print("Loading A01")
       log.info("Loading A01")

       # Execute the SQL query
       result = conn.execute(query)
       
       column_names = result.keys()
       rows = [dict(zip(column_names, row)) for row in result.fetchall()]

       # Create a DataFrame from the list of dictionaries
       globals.a01_df = pd.DataFrame(rows)       `
```

pd.read_sql() does not return valid while fetchall() does on the same query

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/c29e43f476d3ddec4f412f31f92e5050) works fine for me.

Comment: I am using PyCharm - will post some more diagnostic output later - what is diff from conn.execute() and exec_driver_sql ???

Comment: I'm using PyCharm, too. `.exec_driver_sql()` is the SQLAlchemy 2.0 way to execute plain text queries, which also works in 1.4. `.execute("SELECT …")` will raise a `RemovedIn20Warning` in 1.4 and will fail in 2.0.